# Why am I not able to disable mat-stroke-button like this?

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a custom button based on the Angular Material button.

The problem is that, for some reason, I cannot `disable` the button properly anymore. The styles etc work but for some reason it seems that the content inside the `button` still work on the `(click)` event.

See [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkjgmk?file=app/button-overview-example.html) wher you can click the "*Disabled*" as well as the "*Spinner+Disabled*" button.

HTML:

```xml
<button mat-stroked-button [color]="color" [disabled]="disabled || loading" [type]="type">
  <mat-icon *ngIf="icon" [class.hidden]="loading">{{icon}}</mat-icon>
  <span [class.hidden]="loading"><ng-content></ng-content></span>
  <div *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-wrapper">
    <mat-spinner [diameter]="20"></mat-spinner>
  </div>
</button>
```

The component:

```js
import {Component, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.css']
})
export class ButtonComponent {

  @Input() icon: string;

  @Input() color = 'primary';

  @Input() disabled = false;

  @Input() type = 'submit';

  private _loading = false;

  @Input()
  set loading(loading: boolean) {
    this._loading = loading;
  }

  get loading(): boolean {
    return this._loading;
  }

}
```

Styles:

```css
:host {
  display: inline-grid;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.spinner-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Any idea how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution can be the CSS pointer-events: none

👉 button.component.css

```css
:host {
  display: inline-grid;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.spinner-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

/* ######## add this pointer-events acting classes ####### */
.disabled {
  pointer-events: all;
 }

:host{
  pointer-events: none;
 }
```

👉 button.component.html

```html
<!-- and just add [class.disabled]="!disabled" to the button-->
<button mat-stroked-button [color]="color" [disabled]="disabled || loading" [type]="type" [class.disabled]="!disabled">
  <mat-icon *ngIf="icon" [class.hidden]="loading">{{icon}}</mat-icon>
  <span [class.hidden]="loading"><ng-content></ng-content></span>
  <div *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-wrapper">
    <mat-spinner [diameter]="20"></mat-spinner>
  </div>
</button>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-56211649

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this somehow from withing the `app-button` component?

Comment: check the stackblitz now. I i'll change my answer later. i think it works as you need now

Comment: Already changed. Hope it helps and good luck with your project :)

Comment: Yes, that does what it should do. Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `(click)` event is not on the button, but on the `app-button` tag. If you pass the click handler to the component, and set a `(click)` attribute on the button tag, it won't trigger if it's disabled.

Comment: I realize that the StackBlitz does not reproduce what I have here on my machine. On my machine, not the entire button is clickable, only the icon/text but not the areay around it. That's what was confusing me. I'll try to reproduce it.